# change the value of name: in an object in serialize array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing this:

```
        var a_survey = $('#survey-1 :input').serializeArray();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/save_a_survey/",
            type: "post",
            data: a_survey,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}',
        });
```

Which passes this:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken:6rS9oNMSJIzJw6ye8nCQZPRkjNemyMOD
form-1-student:12
form-1-behavior_type:Externalizer
form-1-surveyset:13
```

But I want to change the names of the keys to:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken:6rS9oNMSJIzJw6ye8nCQZPRkjNemyMOD
student:12
behavior_type:Externalizer
surveyset:13
```

This probably seems like quite a hack, but I am dealing with django formsets and trying to save pieces of them at a time; Which may also sound like a hack...

So far I have tried this:

```
    a_survey = $('#survey-1 :input').serializeArray();
    for (var i = 1; i <= a_survey.length; i++) {
        a_survey[i]['name'] = a_survey[i]['name'].replace(/form-\d-/g, "");
    };
```

But I keep getting...

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an off-by-one error in your iteration (JavaScript arrays are zero-based).

```
var a_survey = $('#survey-1 :input').serializeArray();
for (var i = 0; i < a_survey.length; i++) {
    a_survey[i].name = a_survey[i].name.replace(/form-\d-/g, "");
};
```

---

Edit: Alternatively, you can use `$.each()`, per @RobG's suggestion:

```
var a_survey = $('#survey-1 :input').serializeArray();
$.each(a_survey, function(i, item) {
    item.name = item.name.replace(/form-\d-/g, "");
});
```

Comment: +1 — perhaps *forEach* or *$.each* can be used for the iteration?

Comment: Thank you! This worked great. I skipped the first one because it was the csrf token... I didn't think it would generate an  off-by-one error. Is this unique to javascript? I don't think C does this...

Comment: @broinjc: the error comes from `<= x.length`, an that is a problem in every language. The largest accessible index of an array of length 3 is 2 (0,1,2), i.e length - 1.

Comment: @FelixKling OH! Yes, now I see what I did there.